# Override settings variable with custom app

Tags: django, django-admin, django-settings

I am developing a django package that allows to override the admin theme by just placing the app in INSTALLED_APPS before the `django.contrib.admin` line.

I want this application to have more than one theme so you can choose which one to use by setting a variable in the **settings.py** file. So, I have this structure for my themes:

```
myapp
|--templates
   |-- default
   |-- theme1
   |-- theme2
```

If I set that variable to **theme1**, it should load the templates from the directory `templates/theme1`.

Right now, I have written this in the `__init__.py` file of my application:

```
from django.conf import settings

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

default_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/default')
if hasattr(settings, 'ZONEADMIN_THEME'):
    path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/', settings.ZONEADMIN_THEME)
    settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS += ((path,) if os.path.isdir(path) else (default_path,))
else:
    settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS += (default_path,)
```

and it works but I believe there is a better way to do that. Is this piece of code an example of what to write in the `app.ready` function? where should I override the TEMPLATE_DIRS variable?